# How to sort a List<String> using data from a column in a ListView

Tags: c#, sorting, listview

In my application, there is a ListView that contains the Location name and the Picking Priority (Lowest is chosen first) of all the locations that products are kept in. As well as this, I am also creating temporary List's that contain only the locations an individual product is stored in. For example:-

```
          LISTVIEW                                  List<String>
          --------                                  ------------
 __________________________                  __________________________
|Location |Picking Priority|                |         Location         |
|---------|----------------|                |--------------------------|
|    A    |      100       |                |            A             |
|    B    |       50       |                |            C             |
|    C    |      500       |                |            D             |
|    D    |      150       |                |__________________________|
|_________|________________|
```

What I want to happen is the List to be ordered based on the Picking Priority of that location in the ListView, lowest to highest.

In effect, this would mean the List above would now look like this:-

```
 __________________________            
|         Location         |
|--------------------------|
|            A             |
|            D             |
|            C             |
|__________________________|
```

How would this be possible to do?

Comment: Does this must be a List<string>? cannot be a List<yourClass> and define in yourClass a Location and a Priority property? in that way you can do list.OrderBy(d => d.Priority).Select(d => d.Location).ToList();

Comment: Ideally yes, it would have to be List<String> as to not hinder any existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the items based on the listitems, it's ugly, it's slow (slower than using a class with both properties) but it can work.

I assume ListViewItem.Text contains the name of the location and ListViewItem.Subitems[1].Text is the column with the priority (in integer format):

```
var items = theListView.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();
var sortedList = theStringList.OrderBy(d => items.Where(i => i.Text == d).Select(i => int.Parse(i.Subitems[1].Text)).First()).ToList();
```

Comment: This works really well. I agree with you that it would be better to use a class but as an alternative, it still works fairly quickly.